# Bulk edit/update in admin grid pannel

Tags: magento-1.9, massaction

I have created my own grid in magento admin with custom table. Now I would like to edit/update rows from grid panel. So that I can perform bulk edit/update. No need to open each item and edit/update.

I have seen few great extensions. For example this [one](https://amasty.com/extended-product-grid-with-editor.html).

I am sure I need to use some kind of Ajax to achieve this but not sure.

Can anyone guide me to right direction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging up for several hours- I have come across **Atwix**'s [solution](http://www.atwix.com/magento/inline-editing-in-magento-backend-grids/).

Which is pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

for editing in grid column you need to add **'editable' =>true,**

```
$this->addColumn(
'code', array(
'header' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Code'),
'align' => 'left',
'width' => '110px',
'index' => 'code',
'editable' =>true,

)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I am voting up for your answer. Cannot mark as right answer since it's not complete.

Comment: https://github.com/Meabed/magento-regions-manager  check this tutorial for grid edit